# Do magical investigations ever use any muggle techniques?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, crime

For example, in *Goblet of Fire*, when Winky the house elf is found holding Harry's wand after the World Cup attacks, the Ministry of Magic at first wants to take this as proof that Winky conjured the Dark Mark. They even know it was conjured with Harry's wand by using the [reverse spell](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Reverse_Spell). The only problem is that they're fairly sure Winky didn't even know how to perform the spell needed to conjure it, as only Death Eaters seem to know how.

So the Ministry officials all stand around wondering, 'what do we do now?' and meanwhile I'm thinking, **why not just check Harry's Wand for finger prints?** Had they done so, they'd have found prints matching

> Barty Crouch Jr., a convicted Death Eater

This person's prints being found on Harry's wand would certainly have at least pointed the Ministry's investigation in the right direction.

So, do magical investigations ever use Muggle techniques like fingerprints and the like?

Comment: I doubt they take Death Eaters' fingerprints.

Comment: @Adamant I know, but that seems silly to me. lol. Why wouldn't they?

Comment: Generally speaking, because the magical world is contemptuous of Muggle technology, and slow to adopt it.

Comment: It might be that faking false finger prints is one of the most easy spells in the book? Could it not be that one just needs *Polyjuice Potion Lite*, which is a not at all a complex and time-consuming concoction, and thus possible to make by even the unskilled witches and wizards?

Answer (score 7):

The Muggles and the Wizarding world are two very separate communities in HP universe. Their practices and lives are quite different in the sense that the wizards find muggles and their living absurd, apart from a few muggle lovers.

They don't use fingerprinting for the same reason they prefer brooms, apparition etc to cars. They could. No one is stopping them, but they have no need for that. Wizards have magic at their fingertips after all!